# Drive Partition Hidden and Merged into another Partition

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I tried to install software on my Windows having partitions `C:/` and `D:/`.

After the successful installation it asked me to reboot and after doing so, the `D:` drive no longer appeared in My Computer.

My hard drive contains `476 GB` of spaced but when I go to my computer it only shows `C:/` with `239 GB`.

When I go to `This PC > Manage > Disk Management` it shows C with `476 GB`

Now my data in `D:/` is lost and I can't see it and that data is really important. I am on an SSD so I am not sure if recovery software will be able to recover my data

Can someone please help me recover my partition? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you recently update from a previous version of Windows 10?

Comment: Also, could you file a feedback under the area path "Files, Folders, and Online Storage\Disks and Storage" using the Feedback Hub app and then copy the title you used for the feedback here so we can find it?